# find with regular expression to replace file content

Tags: regex, bash, find

I would like to replace recursively (in a project directory) the word 'javax' with 'jakarta'.
That works for files ending in "java":

```
find . -name '*.java' | xargs sed -i 's/javax/jakarta/g'
```

I'd need to do the same also for XML files. To use a single command, I've tried modifying the find expression as follows:

```
find . -regex '^.*\.(java|xml)$'
```

However, no files are found. I've tried as well with:

```
find . -regex '.*/^.*\.(java|xml)$'
```

But still nothing. Can you help me to rewrite the finder expression to use multiple files suffixes?
Thanks

Comment: if your find supporst `-regextype` then you can choose which regex engine to use, now you're using `-regextype posix-egrep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `-name` multiple times to match multiple pattern:

```bash
find . \( -name '*.java' -o -name '*.xml' \) -print0 |
xargs -0 sed -i 's/javax/jakarta/g'
```

If you want to use `-regex` then you should also use `-regexrtype` option for extended regex matching:

```bash
find . -regextype awk -regex '.+\.(java|xml)$' -print0 |
xargs -0 sed -i 's/javax/jakarta/g'
```

Take note of `-print0` and `xargs -0` options to take care of file names with special characters.

Comment: `-regexrtype` is a GNU `find` extension; it will not work on platforms which have a different version of `find`

Comment: On BSD (osx) `find` this would be `find -E . -regex '.+\.(java|xml)$'`